# How to convert latitude and longitude (from gps methods) to a geometry.location Google maps object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I have to work out with some coordinate on google maps, and I need to convert a coordinate like 46.1241241, 11.223235 (get by GPS, trought `position.coords`) to an `geometry.location` Google Maps API 3 object.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you create the coordinates:

```
var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.463688, 9.18814);
var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.0438317, 9.75936230000002);
```